# Disable trigger in another db(Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

Can I create a procedure that disables a trigger in another database? I mean, can I disable it with a database link?
I need it for importing data into a data warehouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Here's how.

In a **remote** database (called `ORCL`), I'm creating a table and a trigger:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    null;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.
```

Furthermore, in the same (**remote**) database, I'm creating a procedure which will disable that trigger. It'll use dynamic SQL as you can't execute DDL in PL/SQL *just like that*:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_disable_trg_test as
  2  begin
  3    execute immediate 'alter trigger trg_test disable';
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Now, in a **local** database, I'm creating a database link to the `ORCL` database:

```
SQL> create database link dbl_scott_orcl
  2    connect to scott
  3    identified by tiger
  4    using 'orcl';

Database link created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select * from dual@dbl_scott_orcl;

D
-
X
```

Yes, it does. Fine. Now, all you have to do is to **call the remote procedure from the local database**:

```
SQL> begin
  2    p_disable_trg_test@dbl_scott_orcl;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Let's check the **remote** database's trigger status:

```
SQL> select trigger_name, status from user_Triggers where trigger_name = 'TRG_TEST';

TRIGGER_NAME                   STATUS
------------------------------ --------
TRG_TEST                       DISABLED

SQL>
```

`DISABLED`, as expected.